# Display current logged in user from database in a text box in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ms-access-2007

So I have an account settings portion of a program I am working on. I am wondering how to display the current logged in user in this window. I am using visual studio express and access 2007. I have learned that, UserNameTextBox.Text = Environment.UserName will display the username of the local machine you are logged into. I have a create new user feature where it will add a new user to the "users table" with username password email and admin. Under my account settings I want the form to display the users "username and email" to allow them to make changes. But i have no idea where to start. I do not want it to display the Windows login, just the username and email from the account logged in with inside the application. This is the LOGINSCREEN form.

Public Class LOGINSCREEN

```
Dim loginerror As String
Public Function login()

    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection 'creates database connection
    Dim User As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim CHEMusers As String 'query
    Dim username As String 'look to db for username
    Dim userpassword As String 'look to db for password
    Dim userfound As Boolean ' condition do loop


    cnn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & "chem.accdb;")

    User.Open("Users", cnn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)

    userfound = False
    login = False

    CHEMusers = "Username ='" & usernameTextBox.Text & "'"

    Do
        User.Find(CHEMusers)

        If User.BOF = False And User.EOF = False Then

            username = User.Fields("Username").Value.ToString

            userpassword = User.Fields("UserPassword").Value.ToString


            If username <> usernameTextBox.Text Then
                User.MoveNext()
            Else
                userfound = True
                If userpassword = PasswordTextBox.Text Then
                    User.Close()
                    cnn.Close()
                    Return True

                Else

                    loginerror = "Password does not match."
                    User.Close()
                    cnn.Close()
                    Return False
                End If
            End If

        Else
            loginerror = "Please enter a valid username."
            User.Close()
            cnn.Close()
            Return False

        End If
    Loop Until userfound = True


    User.Close()
    cnn.Close()
    Return False


End Function

Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click


    If login() = True Then

        MessageBox.Show("You have logged in successfully!", "Login Message")

        Dim portal As New PORTAL
        portal.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    Else
        MessageBox.Show(loginerror, "Login Message")
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: There is not enough information here.  What have you tried so far?  Is there something specific that isn't working?

Comment: Simply don't know where to pull from to get that user that was logged in.

Comment: Logged into what? ... Windows? ... your own application? ... an Access .mdb database with User-Level Security (ULS) enabled? Please [edit] your question clarify.

Comment: so basically, my create user features adds the user. i have the login portion where it will check the db as you see above to log into the application. where I am having trouble as i explained above, is pulling that user name and email address that was just logged into the application and displaying it into another form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
If login() = True Then
    MessageBox.Show("You have logged in successfully!", "Login Message")

    ' Pass the user name to the PORTAL's constructor
    Dim portal As New PORTAL(usernameTextBox.Text)
    portal.Show()
    Me.Hide()
Else
    MessageBox.Show(loginerror, "Login Message")
End If
```

then, in your PORTAL class you give it a constructor that accepts the user name:

```
Class Portal
    ' This is a member variable
    Private _userName As String

    ' This is a constructor that accepts the user name
    Public Sub New(userName As String)
        ' Save the user name into the member variable for future use
        _loggedInUserName = userName
    End Sub
End Class
```

At this point, your PORTAL class now has a variable named _loggedInUserName that holds the user name from the login screen.  So you can do: UserNameTextBox.Text = _loggedInUserName in your form Load event.

Comment: wow thanks, now what if i want the db in my ACCSETTINGS page to find the email address logged in with that account and password, i guess i could use the same code for the password, im looking to be able to let the user edit their email and change their password.

Comment: actually when i add usernametextbox.text in ( ) in PORTAL it says to many arguments to public sub new